# parse JSON data from a URL and display on table view

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

This is how the data is placed at the URL

```
{
"studentsinfo": [
    {
            "id": "100",
            "name": "Adam",
            "email": "adam@example.com",
            "address": "House #33, ABC Lane, ABC CITY 06987",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+1 1234567890",
                "home": "00 123456",
                "office": "00 321654"
            }
    },
    {
            "id": "101",
            "name": "Archbould",
            "email": "archbould@example.com",
            "address": "House #33, ABC Lane, ABC CITY 06987",
            "gender" : "male",
            "phone": {
                "mobile": "+1 1234567890",
                "home": "00 123456",
                "office": "00 321654"
            }
    }
}
```

I have to download it and show on a table view. So far I have been able to download the whole snapshot but not been able to download data of specific nodes.

This is my code :

```
 let urlAsString = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mobilesiri/JSON-Parsing-in-Android/master/index.html"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    //2
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

        // 3
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if (err != nil) {
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        // 4

    println(jsonResult)


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        })
    })
    // 5
    jsonQuery.resume()
}
```

Now my question is how do I download specific node data and show it in a table view.

Comment: you mean you want only specific dictionary to be downloaded or anything else..

Comment: i want all the data to be displayed but in different rows of a table view. according to id's it should be displayed in the table view one by one..

Comment: create an Object that contains all this properties,For each dictionary there should be equivalent object. Make array of those objects.Add the data to each cell from each object at that index.

Comment: help me.. can u code it plz?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Starefossen/689428b6c532d7fec0bb  go through this link..Hope it will help you

Comment: thanks a ton it worked !!! :)

Comment: if so upvote my comment..so it gets noticed by others.who have the same question

Answer (score 0):

Go through following implementation.

- create an Object that contains all this properties,For each
  dictionary there should be equivalent object. Make array of those
  objects.Add the data to each cell from each object at that index.
- Also refer following link

  gist.github.com/Starefossen/689428b6c532d7fec0bb

Gist content:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely()

class RemoteAPI {
    func getData(completionHandler: ((NSArray!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Void {
        let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Turistforeningen&media=software")
        let ses = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = ses.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                return completionHandler(nil, error)
            }

            var error: NSError?
            let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary

            if (error != nil) {
                return completionHandler(nil, error)
            } else {
                return completionHandler(json["results"] as [NSDictionary], nil)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}

var api = RemoteAPI()

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView: UITableView!
    var items: NSMutableArray = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 480)
        self.tableView = UITableView(frame:self.view!.frame)
        self.tableView!.delegate = self
        self.tableView!.dataSource = self
        self.tableView!.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        self.view?.addSubview(self.tableView)

        api.getData({data, error -> Void in
            if (data != nil) {
                self.items = NSMutableArray(array: data)
                self.tableView!.reloadData()
                self.view
            } else {
                println("api.getData failed")
                println(error)
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count;
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        if let navn = self.items[indexPath.row]["trackName"] as? NSString {
            cell.textLabel.text = navn
        } else {
            cell.textLabel.text = "No Name"
        }

        if let desc = self.items[indexPath.row]["description"] as? NSString {
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = desc
        }

        return cell
    }
}

ViewController().view
```